# PHP - funny behaviour of cookie variables and session variables

Tags: php, cookies

I wrote a little PHP script below to demonstrate my question.  Run the code below like this: http://localhost/test.php?test=10, then run http://localhost/test.php?test=11, then http://localhost/test.php?test=12, etc.  You will see that the number echo'ed to your screen is always 1 digit behind the url number?!  Maybe because I cant a cookie and immediately read the same cookie?

```
//If query string has $test, store in session, and cookie for later. 
if($_GET[test]){
  $_SESSION['test'] = $_GET[test];
  setcookie("test", $_GET[test], time()+60*60*24*30*12*10); //10 years
}

//If user comes back later, then get $test from cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE["test"])){
  $_SESSION['test'] = $_COOKIE["test"];
}

echo "session test: " . $_SESSION['test'];
```

Later, I solved the problem with the following code, but solving it is not good enough, I want to know WHY this happened!

This solved it:

```
if($_GET[cid]){
  setcookie("campaignid", $_GET[cid], time()+60*60*24*30*12*10); //10 years
  $_SESSION['campaignid'] = $_GET[cid];
}elseif (isset($_COOKIE["campaignid"])){
  $_SESSION['campaignid'] = $_COOKIE["campaignid"];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe because I cant a cookie and immediately read the same cookie?

Exactly. The cookie you sent is available in $_COOKIE array only in the next request, because the $_COOKIE superglobal array is filled with the data, that comes in the client's request. And at first request it is nothing.

Comment: Or in other words, `setcookie` won't add it to `$_COOKIE` for you. Also, mixing `$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION` like this is just.. well, weird.

Answer (score 1):

1. Technically you didn't start a session (`session_start()`) and you're using undefined constant `test`, however PHP is "intelligent" enough to figure out you mean a string `"test"`.
2. What's exactly the question?

   > Maybe because I cant a cookie and immediately read the same cookie?

   Yes, that's true. You've just proved it.

Comment: Love the quotes on "intelligent". Couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet you are calling `setcookie()`. This sends a HTTP header to the browser. PHP does not update the `$_COOKIES` variable when you call setcookie(). The $_COOKIES variable is updated on the next script invocation, when the cookie is returned by the browser.